# How to populate a Mysql docker container during build of another container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker-compose file that automatically builds a container for my application and a mysql-container that stores all the data.

Within my dockerfile for my application I have a script, that sets up all the database tables and preset values, that are necessary for the application to run. Is it possible to somehow pass the reference of the mysql container to myapplication that during build of myapplication it can access the mysql container?

If so, how can I do that, and if not, how should it be done then?

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
mysql:
  image: mysql/mysql-server
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql-root-password

myapplication:
  command: /home/myapplication/startup.sh
  build: ./..
  dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/myapplication
  ports:
    - "443:443"
    - "8090:8090"
  links:
    - mysql:docker-mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_SERVER: docker-mysql
```

myapplication-dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

EXPOSE 443

ENV applicationPath="/home/application“

COPY . ${applicationPath}

#Execute installationScript
RUN /bin/bash -c "./${applicationPath}/Tools/install_all.sh"
```

Comment: Could you explain about the data `myapplication` shall access? Is that installation data?

Comment: What do you mean with shall access? Its basically just a shell script that performs some sql-statements with the common mysql command and sets up the environment of the application.

Comment: Then add that with a `COPY` command instead of pulling it from a database.

Comment: im not trying to pull something from the database. I want to put data into the database during the build of my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing the `docker-compose build` command, docker will just **build the images** of each service defined in the docker-compose.yml file (in your case `mysql` and `myapplication`), so that means that no container will be run.

Once you execute the `docker-compose run` command, docker will **run a container** per image built previously, one for the `mysql` and another for the `myapplication`. Now that both are up, they can interact with each other.

#### So, what should I do?

I will just execute the install_all.sh script (guessing that it contains the database setup) when running the container and before the startup.sh script is executed. Note that the `mysql` container will only be accessible when it is up, that mean only after the `docker-compose up` execution.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
...
myapplication:
  command: bash -c "/home/myapplication/Tools/install_all.sh && /home/myapplication/startup.sh"
...
```

Also, note that your `myapplication` container has to have installed a mysql-client to be able to communicate with the mysql server. Just adding the below line to your Dockerfile will install it:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-client -y
```

And in your `install_all.sh script`, you can have some calls to mysql like below (that create a database):

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h $DOCKER_MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR -P $DOCKER_MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT -u $DOCKER_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_USER -p $DOCKER_MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS new_database;"
```

Comment: ok, this sounds quite reasonable, and im sure that it would work. But I dont like the fact, that I have to start the database setup each time I start my application container. Isn't there a better solution? Otherwise I think i will have to perform some kind of db setup within the build phase of the mysql container

Comment: Well, at the beginning of your setup script you can check if your application database exists, if so, you can exit of the setup process.

Comment: These `DOCKER_MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR` variables no longer exist in Docker 1.10, they were deprecated a while ago. It should use the hostname.

Comment: I think this is only applied if you use docker-compose version 2